# Getting a single part of string from listview

Tags: java, android, string, android-listview

I have this ListView that displays certain info from my DB table. What I'm trying to do is to get back some info from the ListView item or to be precise extract a number from a string. Look's like this:

```
String xyz = lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

would get me something like this:

```
"NumberOne: "+someNumberFromTable1+"\n"+"NumberTwo: "+someNumberFromTable2
```

or the way it's shown in ListView:

```
NumberOne: someNumberFromTable1
NumberTwo:  someStringFromTable2
```

In this case is there any way for me to extract "someNumberFromTable1" ONLY from this String?

Comment: What's giving me problems is that i dont know if the numbers are gonna be one, two or three digits long...

Comment: It would be great if you could explain your question a bit more with some example?

Comment: Use `Split` function to get your desire string value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a regular expression to match the group of digits. Here's a little program to show you how.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Scratch
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String xyz = "NumberOne: 264\nNumberTwo: someStringFromTable2";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=NumberOne: )([0-9]+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xyz);
        int foundNumber = 0;
        if (matcher.find()) {
            foundNumber = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
        }
        System.out.println(foundNumber);
    }
}
```

The regular expression pattern `(?<=NumberOne: )([0-9]+)` is first using what's called a look-behind `(?<=NumberOne: )` to only match something preceded by the string "NumberOne: ", and then it's specifying to find a group of one or more digits `([0-9]+)`.

Output:

```
264
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `split` method of `String` object. Ex

```
String str = "Number one: 12345789";
String num = str.split(": ")[1];
```